# Directx9 Font Update with int to LPCTSTR conversion

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I'm trying to show the score on the screen. Following code works fine:

```
g_Font = NULL;
D3DXFONT_DESC f = {fontSize,
                    0,
                    400,
                    0,
                    false,
                    DEFAULT_CHARSET,
                    OUT_TT_PRECIS,
                    CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                    DEFAULT_PITCH,
                    fontName};
fontDesc = f;
fontPosition.top = top;
fontPosition.left = left;
fontPosition.right = right;
fontPosition.bottom = bottom;
text = t;
D3DXCreateFontIndirect(device,&fontDesc,&g_Font);
```

Following part is rendered for each frame:

```
g_Font->DrawText(NULL,
        text,
        -1,
        &fontPosition,
        DT_CENTER,
        0xffffffff); //draw text
```

What I want to do is, update the text during runtime. I simply update the text variable since drawing code runs for each frame, but it doesn't work. A simple text works but following construction doesn't work:

```
const size_t buflen = 100;
TCHAR buf[buflen];
_sntprintf(buf, buflen - 1, TEXT("Point: %d"), point);
text = (LPCTSTR)buf;
```

I tried almost every solution I could have found online, but they don't work. I can see that the integer is converted successfully, but there are absurd characters in the following rendering. Any solutions?

Comment: Where is `pointLabel` coming from? can't you simply `DrawText` your new value?

Comment: Yes I can, but it's another class implemented for abstraction; so it's not the point of the question.

Comment: Without us telling us how `setText` on `pointLabel` is implemented there's not much we can tell you... is `pointLabel` rendered?

Comment: " I simply update the text variable" and I updated the code. It's simply assignment operation, forget `pointLabel`

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is incomplete, but I will still try to provide you with an answer that should help you solve the problem.

The first issue is I think you're mixing concepts and you're handling `DrawText` like if it was a UI element of a `WinForms` or something. Everytime you want to update the text, `DrawText` needs to be called. It doesn't store a pointer to the buffer you pass and automatically update the text when this buffer is changed, see documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you wanted to add a "label wrapper", you will need to have it call `DrawText`, most likely in a `Render` method, between calls to `BeginScene` and `EndScene`.

As for the absurd characters, if your string is converted properly, are you sure you `Clear` your `RenderTarget` before drawing again on it?